# Proving Inequality relation on integer set.

Tags: proof-writing

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, Suppose $a<b\;\land a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove $b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. I am having trouble using only the axioms of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $a \in Z^+$ then $a > 0$. Since $a < b$, we have $0 < a < b$ by transitive property. Hence, $b \in Z^+$.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I was trying to $b-a>0$ and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Initially I thought that because you have b > a and the definition of b > a is b - a > 0. The main trick was realizing that $a \in Z^+$ implies $a > 0$.